# Resharper Naming Style for C# loop and range variables

Tags: resharper

I'm trying to configure ReSharper for a project where the C# local variable naming conventions are different from the loop and range variable naming conventions.

Local variables within a method body should be UpperCamelCase, except for loop and range variables which should be lowerCamelCase.

Examples:

```
int[] SomeArray;

for(int i=0; i<SomeArray.Length; i++)
{
}

foreach(var someValue in SomeArray)
{
}

return  from someValue in SomeArray
        where someValue > 0
        select someValue;
```

Is it possible to configure this convention in ReSharper?  As far as I can tell, none of the available C# naming style rules seem to cover loop / range variables.

I'm using ReSharper 6.1 and Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, Resharper cannot differentiate between local variables and loop / range variables (which are also local variables too).

I would suggest either sticking to the Microsoft naming scheme for all local variables of lowerCamelCase or just suppress that check or set it to 'Do not show'.

Comment: Thanks - for now I've just changed the Resharper warning to a suggestion.